# How can I refer to the model (backbone) where I'm inside?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to set some attributes to a model inside an ajax call inside the model, but it doesn't work.I've used this.set in the success function of ajax call but doesn't work. I don't know the exactly means of this.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/", defaults:{},
    initialize:function(){
      var self=this.persona;
      console.log("inperson");
      this.upload();    
    },     
    validate:function(){
      console.log("validate");
    },
    upload:function(){
      var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + file.name;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'qS0KLMx**1tyhM9EEPiTS3VMk');
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'nh3eoUo9*s9VQzvbF2gMhcKJIfIt1Gm');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
        },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("File available at: " + data.name);
          this.set({image: {"name" :data.name, "__type" : "File"}});//THE PROBLEM IS HERE!!
        },
        error: function(data) {
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          alert(obj.error);
        }
      });            
    }
 });
 return Person;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

As underscorejs is a dependency of backbonejs you can use the `_.bind` helper:

> `_.bind(func [, thisArg, arg1, arg2, …])`
>
> Creates a function that, when called, invokes `func` with the `this`
>   binding of `thisArg` and prepends any additional bind arguments to those
>   passed to the bound function.

http://underscorejs.org/#bind

http://lodash.com/docs#bind

```
success: _.bind(function(data) {
  console.log("File available at: " + data.name);
  this.set({image: {"name" :data.name, "__type" : "File"}});
}, this)
```

This will allow you to access `this` inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` uses their own context (`this`) in the `success`/`error` callbacks.

An good approach (and using less chars) would be the following:

```
var model = this;
$.ajax({
  // Other properties come here
  success: function() {
    console.log("File available at: " + data.name);
    model.set({ image: { "name": data.name, "__type" : "File" } });
  }
})
```